# Is it possible to write "I am knowing" in this case

Tags: present-continuous, lyrics

I know lyrics sometimes do not respect grammar, but is it possible to use to know in the progressive form? For example -

> I'm not even knowing if I'm coming or going, if to end or begin.

This is from a song of the Buzzcocks written by Peter Shelley  "I believe"

Comment: Song lyrics often take liberties with grammar. This line includes the grammatically incorrect words "I'm not even knowing" because the correct version "I don't even know" would not rhyme with "if I'm coming or going". To find out why it is incorrect, take a look at the related question- link above.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:
If I read the phrase "I am knowing", such as "I am knowing the information", it certainly appears to be a grammatical error.
However, song lyrics and poetry allow artistic license, where it's common to say otherwise unexpected things, and that appears to be the case here.

Comment: Indeed. Most egregious case being Paul McCartney in 'Live and Let Die' with the line `'But if this ever-changing world in which we live in...'`. Drives me mad, not because I'm a grammar pedant, but because `'But if this ever-changing world in which we're living ...'` would have solved the scansion problem McCartney was trying to work around perfectly.

Comment: @fred2 , many lyrics websites actually say it's "world in which we're living".  Difficult to know for sure which of those McCartney sings, could be either.

Comment: Maybe, but my suspicion is that that's post facto correction by the lyric transcribers ;-)